# Why there is no "Forgot Email"?

Tags: forms, login, email, accounts, addresses

I noticed, if you forget your password, you need to click "Forgot Password". But if no other way while that multiple email address inputs still doesn't work. They don't provide us an access to Account Recovery Link.

In Twitter, if you forgot your email (number and username), they don't have an access to recover your account.
[image]

In Instagram, they don't have account recovery link either.
[image]

Good thing with Facebook, they allow you to "recover" your account if you missed your email.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This will depend on what options you have if you really forgot your sign-in email. Sites which necessarily need your phone no. to provide their services do have the alternative to login using either your phone no. or email (e.g Instagram as in the image above). Alternatively, an additional email account is used as 'Recovery Email' address (e.g. Gmail and Apple).

Typing wrong email is going to activate security measures for sure to prevent against Bots and brute login attempts. No hints can be supplied to recover the correct email except may be 'Capslock is on' or 'This is not a valid email address' or 'This email-domain is blocked on this site' or 'Email is not registered on this site'.

Devices have built in site and password manager which will store the correct login credentials as long as it is enabled. These password managers may be used to provide email and password suggestions to the user.

One of the best alternatives would be to provide bio-metric login (fingerprint or face scan).

Related question:
[What is best practice for a forgotten login email address?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/83841/what-is-best-practice-for-a-forgotten-login-email-address)